# KeyPressed event not happening?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, keyevent

this code builds correctly and everything appears to work but the key do nothing. I think it's either the action listener or the oval is not updating. I am trying to work through a beginners java game programming. I am sure it's something easy but I am not catching it. I am on a mac in sublime text 2 if that makes a difference.

```
package javagame;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JavaGame extends JFrame {

int x, y;

public class AL extends KeyAdapter {

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keycode = e.getKeyCode();
        if(keycode == e.VK_LEFT); {
            x-= 3;
        }
        if(keycode == e.VK_RIGHT); {
            x+= 3;
        }
        if(keycode == e.VK_UP); {
            y-= 3;
        }
        if(keycode == e.VK_DOWN); {
            y+= 3;
        }
    }


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}

public JavaGame() {
    addKeyListener(new AL());
    setTitle("Jave Game");
    setSize(700, 700);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    x = 350;
    y = 350;
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15);

    repaint();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new JavaGame();
}

}
```

Comment: When in doubt, make the problem simplier. Verify first that you are getting into the `keyPressed` via a `System.out.println` statement, then that the right key was pressed, and finally if you are updating the paint blob.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the semi-colons from your `if` statements:

```
if (keycode == e.VK_LEFT)
{
   x-= 3;
}
```

Currently the code blocks that follow your `if` statements are rendered free standing as the semi-colons terminate those statements.

---

Some `Swing`-specific notes:

- It's better to use `paintComponent` from a sub-classed `JComponent` for better paint 
  performance.
- Use [Key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener` for improved key event management. Here is an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/ListingtheKeyBindingsinaComponent.htm).

Comment: You should show him a simple example of how to use Key bindings.

Comment: wow i don't even know why i put those in there. thanks I figured it was something obvious. i appreciate the quick answer and the helpful links I am really new to coding but im getting a little better at least.

Comment: @SavgStorm Everyone is getting better by practice. Not only the "new" ones. The best way to learn coding (in my opinion) is to actually code. Therefore I guess you are on the right track. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Even with the suggested corrections, you are still going to have possible issues.

Firstly, `JFrame` actually contains a number of components on top of it, the root pane, which contains the content and layered panes and the glass pane (which is typically invisible).  If any of these components obtain key board focus for any reason, you key listener is likely to be ignored.

A better solution would be to use the [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API, which provides finer control over the focus issues.

You've also violated the paint contract.  You are required, under most circumstances, to call `super.paint`, in fact, you are discouraged for overriding the paint method of top level containers, instead, you would extend from something like `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent` method instead.

These paint methods perform very important work and you should not ignore/skip them lightly.  Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Custom Painting in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more info

Comment: i think he is doing it that way for simplicity at the moment. but yea I think a lot of this is not proper it's just to teach the basic idea of having something move on the screen. the next tutorial switches to using an image and threads. thanks for the info though.